# Обновление переменной каждую секунду

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, время, threading

Есть код:

```
    import time
    import datetime


    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    h = now.hour
    m = now.minute
    s = now.second
    print(h, ':', m, ':', s)
    time.sleep(1)

    print(h, ':', m, ':', s)
    time.sleep(5)

    print(h, ':', m, ':', s)
```

Нужно, чтобы каждый раз при команде `print` выдавалось разное значение (для этого и добавил секунды). Однако, выдаётся лишь то значение, при котором программа была запущена (логично!). \

Циклы, типа `while 1 == 1`, переменные далее `print` не выводит собственно `print`. 
Думаю, что можно задавать переменные непосредственно перед командой `print`, но уверен, что есть вариант меньше по размеру кода и эффективнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

def TaskManager():
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    t = Timer( 1, TaskManager )
    t.start()

TaskManager()
```

---

```
22:13:12
22:13:13
22:13:14
22:13:15
22:13:16
22:13:17
...
```

Comment: А почему не использовать один таймер?

Answer (score 2):

Ну Вы же лишь единожды определяете переменные и потом значения заранее определённые выводите через `print` через промежуток времени. Вам нужно их либо пепреопределять, либо без них обходиться, если я правильно понял

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

print(datetime.now().hour,":",datetime.now().minute,":",datetime.now().second)
sleep(1)
print(datetime.now().hour,":",datetime.now().minute,":",datetime.now().second)
sleep(5)
print(datetime.now().hour,":",datetime.now().minute,":",datetime.now().second)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time 
import datetime     
while 1 == 1:
        global h, m, s
        time.sleep(1)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        h = now.hour
        m = now.minute
        s = now.second
        print(h, ":", m, ":", s)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(h, ":", m, ":", s)
        time.sleep(5)
        print(h, ":", m, ":", s)
```

Вот правильный ответ, который ищет этот человек, а вариант от nobody не подходит, т.к. обновление идёт ЛИШЬ ОДИН РАЗ, для полного обновления необходимо, чтобы  проходило
 `now = datetime.datetime.now()`.